# I'm having issues with turning on the security on my bot, using Azure and the MS bot framework as well as LUIS

Tags: azure, bots

When I change the MS App ID and password for my bot from the null value to the actual values as supplied by MS, then the whole thing stops working locally and definitely also when it is deployed.
It works just as long as those values are null but clearly it cannot be deployed like that.

var connector = new builder.ChatConnector({
        appId: null,
        appPassword: null
});

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you verify that the app ID and password that your bot will use for authentication are valid by issuing HTTP request to the microsoft login service?

To verify that your bot's app ID and password are valid, issue the following request using cURL, replacing APP_ID and APP_PASSWORD with your bot's app ID and password.

```
curl -k -X POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token -d "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default"
```

This request attempts to exchange your bot's app ID and password for an access token. If the request is successful, you will receive a JSON payload that contains an access_token property, amongst others.

Detailed steps are also available from Azure [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-2).

If the above result provides a access_token you can [enable security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-troubleshoot-authentication-problems?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#step-3-enable-security-and-test-on-localhost-) and test the bot locally before deploying it.

Comment: seems to work just fine!  Here's the output: {"token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"ext_expires_in":3600,"access_token":"VERY_LONG_TOKEN"}    ...but when I put those same credentials into the bot, it doesn't respond.

Comment: restify listening to http://[::]:3978
ERROR: ChatConnector: receive - invalid token. Requested by unexpected app ID.